# Import as alias in variable declaration assignment

Tags: javascript

In import we can restructure the object from a module.

```
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
```

Why can't we do the same for an object coming from a function?

Such as this:

```
const example = () => ({greeting: 'Hello World'})
const {greeting as welcome} = example()
console.log(welcome)
```

Comment: Why? Are you hoping one of the authors of the spec chime in?

Comment: Because destructuring works very different than imports.

Answer (score 4):

```
const {greeting : welcome} = example()
```

You can without the `as` operator. Probably the `as` operator was invented because of the confusion that comes with the syntax above.

Comment: I wouldn't call `as` an operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can already do this. Straight from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> **Assigning to new variable names**
>
> A property can be unpacked from an
>   object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the
>   object property.
>
> ```
> var o = {p: 42, q: true};
> var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;  
> console.log(foo); // 42
> console.log(bar); // true
> ```